# Storing firestore objects in an array then sorting based on a numerical key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

**Context**

- I've just queried all offers a specific user is eligible for, and
  have stored those objects in an array.
- I'm now looking to sort them
  by priority (`pri`) so that I can place the first three on the user's
  dashboard
- The sorting isn't happening, and I'm struggling to figure out why.

**Code**

```
    var offers = new Object;

    var offers = snap.data().offers;

    var offerpriority = new Array;

    offers.forEach(offer => {

        db.collection("offers").doc(offer).get().then(snap => {

            var thisoffer = {title: snap.data().title, pri: snap.data().priority};
            offerpriority.push(thisoffer);

        });

    });

    function compare(a, b){
        return b.pri-a.pri;
    };


    console.log(offerpriority.sort(compare));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `orderBy()` method in order to sort items in Firestore.

You should use something like :

```
db.collection("offers").orderBy("pri");
```

Moreover, if you want to limit the results, like displaying 3 of them you can use the `limit()` method:

```
db.collection("offers").orderBy("pri").limit(3);
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) you can find a more detailed documentation regarding this discussion.

Comment: There's only a handful of offers that I want to get, the ones that appear in my user's offer array. Where would you think about adding that in?

Comment: Probably for this you should iterate through the array and do a comparison query for each of the array element using the where('offers', '=', arrayElement) method. This solution is not so efficient, but I cannot think of anything else for the moment.